# Add DTB to u-boot uImage during Yocto build

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

I have a manual process for compiling a Linux kernel for an embedded ARM device. I use the `CONFIG_APPENDED_DTB=y` option, append my DTB file to the zImage file, then convert to uImage:

```
cat arch/arm/boot/zImage ./arch/arm/boot/dts/lpc3250-phy3250.dtb > arch/arm/boot/zImage-dtb
mkimage -A arm -O linux -C none -T kernel -a 0x80008000 -e 0x80008000 -n 'Linux' \
    -d arch/arm/boot/zImage-dtb arch/arm/boot/uImage
```

I'm attempting to migrate to Yocto. How can I implement the same process? I can set `KERNEL_IMAGETYPE = "zImage"` but I'm not sure how to postprocess the zImage file.

Note that my version of u-boot is fixed and quite old, so I am not currently considering migrating to other formats such as FIT.

I am a newcomer to Yocto, so expository answers are especially welcome.

Comment: Looks like the `meta-ti` layer has a [`bundle-devicetree.inc`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-ti/tree/recipes-kernel/linux/bundle-devicetree.inc) with this purpose. Maybe [this patch](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/150768/) was intending to implement it but wasn't merged.

Comment: I think the `meta-ti` solution is incorrect because the resulting uImage header's [data size field](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/d71dbe657c3c22f50ecb3df133e5cdd884daae7d/include/image.h#L268) will be invalid.

Comment: I think there is an option to have the kernel build append the DTB, so you don't need `cat`.  You have to have the name of the DTB to append in the *.config*.  It is attached like an [initial ramdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk), by the kernel build.  I recall having troubles when doing both but can not recall the details and my kernel versions was the late 2.6 series or 3.x.